# Check for Folder exists using DTUTIL

Tags: sql, windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a DtUTIL command in loop where its is creating a folder and deploying it 
but ima getting The CreateFolderOnSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80040E2F (The statement has been terminated.) The SQL statement issued has failed.
Error.Code is as follows

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ( 'dir /s /b /a-d "%relroot%\*.dtsx" ') DO (
FOR /f "delims=" %%m IN ("%%~dpi.") DO (
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ("%%~dpm.") DO (
dtutil /sources %ServerName%  /fc "SQL;%MYDIR1%\%MYDIR2%;%%~nq"
)
```

Error is due to dtutil /sources %ServerName%  /fc "SQL;%MYDIR1%\%MYDIR2%;%%~nq"
Kindly suggest a way to check if folder exixts create else dont create

Answer (score 2):

Check, if the folder exists:

```
if not exist "%MYDIR1%\%MYDIR2%\%%~nq\" 
    dtutil /sources %ServerName%  /fc "SQL;%MYDIR1%\%MYDIR2%;%%~nq"
) else (
    echo "%MYDIR1%\%MYDIR2%\%%~nq" already exists
    rem do anything other
)
```